# AD users don't get added to groups by powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a script for adding a user to the active directory. The user gets created (although there are some issues for which I'll create separate questions), but the user is not added to the groups, with the error that groups were not found. But I confirmed the groups are in the AD. This is the code I have now:

```
$Orig_exec_policy = Get-ExecutionPolicy
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force
<# This form was created using POSHGUI.com  a free online gui designer for PowerShell
.NAME
    Untitled
#>

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

#region Window properties
$AD_user_creation                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$AD_user_creation.ClientSize     = '480,740'
$AD_user_creation.text           = "AD user creation - WG Mustang"
$AD_user_creation.TopMost        = $false
#endregion

[void]$AD_user_creation.SuspendLayout()

#region Real name of the user
$Display_name_lbl                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Display_name_lbl.text           = "User`'s real name"
$Display_name_lbl.AutoSize       = $true
$Display_name_lbl.width          = 25
$Display_name_lbl.height         = 10
$Display_name_lbl.location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10)

$First_name_val                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$First_name_val.multiline        = $false
$First_name_val.width            = 120
$First_name_val.height           = 20
$First_name_val.location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,10)

$Second_name_val                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Second_name_val.multiline       = $false
$Second_name_val.width           = 120
$Second_name_val.height          = 20
$Second_name_val.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(330,10)

$Display_name_val                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Display_name_val.Text           = ""
$Display_name_val.width          = 250
$Display_name_val.height         = 20
$Display_name_val.location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,40)
#endregion

#region User name of the user
$User_name_lbl                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$User_name_lbl.text              = "User logon name"
$User_name_lbl.AutoSize          = $true
$User_name_lbl.width             = 25
$User_name_lbl.height            = 10
$User_name_lbl.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,70)

$User_name_val                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$User_name_val.multiline         = $false
$User_name_val.width             = 250
$User_name_val.height            = 20
$User_name_val.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,70)
#endregion

#region Account password
$Password_lbl                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Password_lbl.text               = "Password"
$Password_lbl.AutoSize           = $true
$Password_lbl.width              = 25
$Password_lbl.height             = 10
$Password_lbl.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,100)

$Password_ini_val                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
$Password_ini_val.multiline      = $false
$Password_ini_val.width          = 250
$Password_ini_val.height         = 20
$Password_ini_val.UseSystemPasswordChar = $true
$Password_ini_val.location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,100)

$Password_conf_val               = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
$Password_conf_val.multiline     = $false
$Password_conf_val.width         = 250
$Password_conf_val.height        = 20
$Password_conf_val.UseSystemPasswordChar = $true
$Password_conf_val.location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,130)
#endregion

#region Location of the user
$Location_lbl                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Location_lbl.text               = "Location"
$Location_lbl.AutoSize           = $true
$Location_lbl.width              = 25
$Location_lbl.height             = 10
$Location_lbl.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,160)

$Location_val                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Location_val.multiline          = $false
$Location_val.text               = "OU=Users,OU=ADM,DC=Domain,DC=com"
$Location_val.width              = 250
$Location_val.height             = 20
$Location_val.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,160)
#endregion

#region Checkboxes
$Must_chg_pass                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Must_chg_pass.text              = "User must change password at next logon"
$Must_chg_pass.AutoSize          = $false
$Must_chg_pass.width             = 290
$Must_chg_pass.height            = 20
$Must_chg_pass.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,190)

$Cannot_chg_pass                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Cannot_chg_pass.text            = "User cannot change password"
$Cannot_chg_pass.AutoSize        = $false
$Cannot_chg_pass.width           = 250
$Cannot_chg_pass.height          = 20
$Cannot_chg_pass.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,220)
$Cannot_chg_pass.Checked         = $true

$Pass_not_expires                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Pass_not_expires.text           = "Password never expires"
$Pass_not_expires.AutoSize       = $false
$Pass_not_expires.width          = 250
$Pass_not_expires.height         = 20
$Pass_not_expires.location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,250)
$Pass_not_expires.Checked        = $true

$Account_disabled_val            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Account_disabled_val.text       = "Account is active"
$Account_disabled_val.AutoSize   = $false
$Account_disabled_val.width      = 250
$Account_disabled_val.height     = 20
$Account_disabled_val.location   = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,280)
$Account_disabled_val.Checked    = $false
#endregion

#region Description
$GECOS_lbl                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$GECOS_lbl.text                  = "Description"
$GECOS_lbl.AutoSize              = $true
$GECOS_lbl.width                 = 25
$GECOS_lbl.height                = 10
$GECOS_lbl.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,310)

$GECOS_val                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$GECOS_val.multiline             = $false
$GECOS_val.width                 = 250
$GECOS_val.height                = 20
$GECOS_val.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,310)
#endregion

#region Group membership
$ADGroups_lbl                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$ADGroups_lbl.text               = "AD Groups"
$ADGroups_lbl.AutoSize           = $true
$ADGroups_lbl.width              = 25
$ADGroups_lbl.height             = 10
$ADGroups_lbl.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,340)

$ADGroups_val                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$ADGroups_val.multiline          = $true
$ADGroups_val.width              = 250
$ADGroups_val.height             = 160
$ADGroups_val.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,340)
#endregion

#region Additional attributes
$Ext_Attribute5_lbl              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Ext_Attribute5_lbl.Text         = "Extension Attribute5"
$Ext_Attribute5_lbl.AutoSize     = $true
$Ext_Attribute5_lbl.Width        = 25
$Ext_Attribute5_lbl.Height       = 10
$Ext_Attribute5_lbl.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,510)

$Ext_Attribute5_val              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Ext_Attribute5_val.Text         = "Company name"
$Ext_Attribute5_val.Multiline    = $false
$Ext_Attribute5_val.Width        = 250
$Ext_Attribute5_val.Height       = 20
$Ext_Attribute5_val.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,510)

$Ext_Attribute10_lbl             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Ext_Attribute10_lbl.Text        = "Extension Attribute10"
$Ext_Attribute10_lbl.AutoSize    = $true
$Ext_Attribute10_lbl.Width       = 25
$Ext_Attribute10_lbl.Height      = 10
$Ext_Attribute10_lbl.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,540)

$Ext_Attribute10_val             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Ext_Attribute10_val.Text        = "Region"
$Ext_Attribute10_val.Multiline   = $false
$Ext_Attribute10_val.Width       = 250
$Ext_Attribute10_val.Height      = 20
$Ext_Attribute10_val.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,540)

$Ext_Attribute15_lbl             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Ext_Attribute15_lbl.Text        = "Extension Attribute15"
$Ext_Attribute15_lbl.AutoSize    = $true
$Ext_Attribute15_lbl.Width       = 25
$Ext_Attribute15_lbl.Height      = 10
$Ext_Attribute15_lbl.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,570)

$Ext_Attribute15_val             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Ext_Attribute15_val.Text        = "EH/WH"
$Ext_Attribute15_val.Multiline   = $false
$Ext_Attribute15_val.Width       = 250
$Ext_Attribute15_val.Height      = 20
$Ext_Attribute15_val.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,570)

$Job_Title_lbl                   = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Job_Title_lbl.Text              = "Job title"
$Job_Title_lbl.AutoSize          = $true
$Job_Title_lbl.Width             = 25
$Job_Title_lbl.Height            = 10
$Job_Title_lbl.Location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,600)

$Job_Title_val                   = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Job_Title_val.Text              = "NA"
$Job_Title_val.Multiline         = $false
$Job_Title_val.Width             = 250
$Job_Title_val.Height            = 20
$Job_Title_val.Location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,600)

$Department_lbl                  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Department_lbl.Text             = "Department"
$Department_lbl.AutoSize         = $true
$Department_lbl.Width            = 25
$Department_lbl.Height           = 10
$Department_lbl.Location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,630)

$Department_val                  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Department_val.Text             = "NA"
$Department_val.Multiline        = $false
$Department_val.Width            = 250
$Department_val.Height           = 20
$Department_val.Location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,630)

$Company_lbl                     = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Company_lbl.Text                = "Company"
$Company_lbl.AutoSize            = $true
$Company_lbl.Width               = 25
$Company_lbl.Height              = 10
$Company_lbl.Location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,660)

$Company_val                     = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Company_val.Text                = "IBM"
$Company_val.Multiline           = $false
$Company_val.Width               = 250
$Company_val.Height              = 20
$Company_val.Location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,660)
#endregion

#region Buttons
$Confirm_Button                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Confirm_Button.BackColor        = "#00ff00"
$Confirm_Button.text             = "OK"
$Confirm_Button.width            = 100
$Confirm_Button.height           = 30
$Confirm_Button.location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,690)
$Confirm_Button.Font             = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10,style=Bold'
$Create_ADuser = {
  if ($Password_ini_val.Text -cne $Password_conf_val.Text)
  {
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Passwords don't match")
  } elseif ($Password_ini_val.Text.Length -lt 8)
  {
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Password is too short")
  } else {
    $password = $Password_ini_val.Text | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $Display_name = $Display_name_val.Text + " [ADM]"
    New-ADUser -GivenName $First_name_val.Text -Surname $Second_name_val.Text -DisplayName $Display_name -AccountPassword $password -Path $Location_val.Text -Name $User_name_val.Text`
     -CannotChangePassword $Cannot_chg_pass.Checked -PasswordNeverExpires $Pass_not_expires.Checked -ChangePasswordAtLogon $Must_chg_pass.Checked -Enabled $Account_disabled_val.Checked`
     -Description $GECOS_val.Text -OtherAttributes @{'ExtensionAttribute5' = $Ext_Attribute5_val.Text;'ExtensionAttribute9' = "People";'ExtensionAttribute10' = $Ext_Attribute10_val.Text;`
     'ExtensionAttribute11' = "Other";'ExtensionAttribute12' = "No";'ExtensionAttribute14' = "NA";'ExtensionAttribute15' = $Ext_Attribute15_val.Text;'Division' = "WG Mustang"}`
     -Office "NA" -OfficePhone "NA" -Title $Job_Title_val.Text -Department $Department_val.Text -Company $Company_val.Text -SamAccountName $User_name_val.Text -PassThru | `
     Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf $ADGroups_val.Text
    $AD_user_creation.Close()
  }
}
$Confirm_Button.add_Click($Create_ADuser)


$Cancel_button                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Cancel_button.BackColor         = "#ff0000"
$Cancel_button.text              = "Cancel"
$Cancel_button.width             = 100
$Cancel_button.height            = 30
$Cancel_button.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(350,690)
$Cancel_button.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10,style=Bold'
<#$Cancel = {
    $AD_user_creation.Close()
    exit
}#>
$Cancel_button.add_Click({
    $AD_user_creation.Close()
    exit
})

$AD_user_creation.AcceptButton   = $Confirm_Button
$AD_user_creation.CancelButton   = $Cancel_button
#endregion

$AD_user_creation.controls.AddRange(@($Display_name_lbl,$First_name_val,$Second_name_val,$User_name_lbl,$Display_name_val,$User_name_val,$Password_lbl,$Password_ini_val,$Password_conf_val,$Location_lbl,`
$Location_val,$Must_chg_pass,$Cannot_chg_pass,$Pass_not_expires,$Account_disabled_val,$GECOS_lbl,$GECOS_val,$ADGroups_lbl,$ADGroups_val,$Ext_Attribute5_lbl,$Ext_Attribute5_val,$Ext_Attribute10_lbl,`
$Ext_Attribute10_val,$Ext_Attribute15_lbl,$Ext_Attribute15_val,$Job_Title_lbl,$Job_Title_val,$Department_lbl,$Department_val,$Company_lbl,$Company_val,$Confirm_Button,$Cancel_button))

$showFullName = { $Display_name_val.Text = ($First_name_val.Text + " " + $Second_name_val.Text) }

[void]$Second_name_val.Add_Leave( { & $showFullName } )
[void]$First_name_val.Add_Leave(  { & $showFullName } )

[void]$AD_user_creation.ResumeLayout()

$result = $AD_user_creation.ShowDialog()
[void]$AD_user_creation.Dispose()

Set-ExecutionPolicy $Orig_exec_policy -Force
```

Originally I didn't put the `-passthru` parameter to the New-ADUser (row 268) and added the `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` cmdlet at a separate row with `-Identity` parameter instead, but tried the actual solution in the code above, when that didn't work. I verified that the `$ADGroups_val.Text` contains the group names put in the respective textbox.
Any idea why the groups aren't added?

Comment: You should post only that part of code where you are stuck. You should show a minimal reproducible example. BTW the new-aduser cmdlet parameters are lot so consider using splatting there.

Comment: Well several times when I pasted just a portion of the code relevant to the question I was asked to post the code as a whole, so I did that right away now. And what do you mean by splatting?

Comment: I see that `$ADGroups_val` is flagged `multiline`.  Try something like `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf $($ADGroups_val.Text.Split( [System.Environment]::NewLine ).ForEach( {$_.Trim()}).Where( {$_}))`

Comment: I think the same. `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` is expecting either a one line text or an array of text. If you are providing multiline input, u have to convert it to an array.

Comment: As for the creation of the user, see my answer in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60225286/9898643) that explains to use splatting to avoid the mistakes you now have with the backticks.

Comment: Nice, it works. Can you please write it below as an answer so that I can mark it as a working solution? And to give credit where's credit due? When I viewed the content of the value it looked precisely the same as if I defined the value as a regular array, so I thought it works as intended. And the error message was "Can't find <group1> in domain; Can't find <grou2> in domain" etc. So I thought the variable was loaded as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

The coding you use for the `New-ADUser` cmdlet has some bad formatting problems. Because of this, it is hard to spot that some backticks are in the wrong place.

Using [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) helps the code to become more readable/maintainable.

By capturing the output of `New-ADUser` in a variable (for that you need to add the `PassThru` switch), you can first test if the new user is created or not and only if you have a valid user object, add it to the group:

```
$params = @{
    'GivenName'             = $First_name_val.Text
    'Surname'               = $Second_name_val.Text
    'DisplayName'           = $Display_name
    'AccountPassword'       = $password
    'Path'                  = $Location_val.Text
    'Name'                  = $User_name_val.Text
    'CannotChangePassword'  = $Cannot_chg_pass.Checked
    'PasswordNeverExpires'  = $Pass_not_expires.Checked
    'ChangePasswordAtLogon' = $Must_chg_pass.Checked
    'Enabled'               = $Account_disabled_val.Checked
    'Description'           = $GECOS_val.Text
    'Office'                = "NA"
    'OfficePhone'           = "NA"
    'Title'                 = $Job_Title_val.Text
    'Department'            = $Department_val.Text
    'Company'               = $Company_val.Text
    'SamAccountName'        = $User_name_val.Text
    'OtherAttributes'       = @{'ExtensionAttribute5'  = $Ext_Attribute5_val.Text
                                'ExtensionAttribute9'  = "People"
                                'ExtensionAttribute10' = $Ext_Attribute10_val.Text
                                'ExtensionAttribute11' = "Other"
                                'ExtensionAttribute12' = "No"
                                'ExtensionAttribute14' = "NA"
                                'ExtensionAttribute15' = $Ext_Attribute15_val.Text
                                'Division'             = "WG Mustang"}
    'PassThru'              = $true
}
$newUser = New-ADUser @params
if ($newUser) {
    $newUser | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf $ADGroups_val.Text
}
else {
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Error creating new user")
}
```

Comment: This is answer to a differen question of mine :-) This was about adding the users to their groups. That was solved by the solution in JosefZ's comment.

Comment: You asked to add it as answer but didn't 'ping' anyone (`@username`) and because this request came directly following my comment, I assumed you meant me. @JosefZ indeed spotted the multiline mistake in the code and should be credited for that, but in this question again you showed the flawed `New-ADUser` code, so here both remedies are needed to make things work.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mention anyone, because unfortunately I started writing my comment before you posted yours, forgot to confirm it and when I finally did, it was after you posted yours, which I didn't see on the unrefreshed page. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @PetrSynek Ah, I see. Happens to everyone  at some point. Sorry I assumed too quickly.