# Checkboxes in powershell GUI not working as supposed to

Tags: powershell, user-interface, active-directory

I have a GUI created in powershell, which contains some checkboxes. Later in the script I use the values from the checkboxes to set parameters of a user account, but it seems the script doesn't take the values as intended. I mean, sometimes the account is created with correct values, sometimes not. I wasn't able to discover any pattern when it works and when not.

```
$Orig_exec_policy = Get-ExecutionPolicy
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force
<# This form was created using POSHGUI.com  a free online gui designer for PowerShell
.NAME
    Untitled
#>

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

#region Window properties
$AD_user_creation                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$AD_user_creation.ClientSize     = '480,740'
$AD_user_creation.text           = "AD user creation - WG Mustang"
$AD_user_creation.TopMost        = $false
#endregion

[void]$AD_user_creation.SuspendLayout()

#region Real name of the user
$Display_name_lbl                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Display_name_lbl.text           = "User`'s real name"
$Display_name_lbl.AutoSize       = $true
$Display_name_lbl.width          = 25
$Display_name_lbl.height         = 10
$Display_name_lbl.location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10)

$First_name_val                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$First_name_val.multiline        = $false
$First_name_val.width            = 120
$First_name_val.height           = 20
$First_name_val.location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,10)

$Second_name_val                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Second_name_val.multiline       = $false
$Second_name_val.width           = 120
$Second_name_val.height          = 20
$Second_name_val.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(330,10)

$Display_name_val                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Display_name_val.Text           = ""
$Display_name_val.width          = 250
$Display_name_val.height         = 20
$Display_name_val.location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,40)
#endregion

#region User name of the user
$User_name_lbl                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$User_name_lbl.text              = "User logon name"
$User_name_lbl.AutoSize          = $true
$User_name_lbl.width             = 25
$User_name_lbl.height            = 10
$User_name_lbl.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,70)

$User_name_val                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$User_name_val.multiline         = $false
$User_name_val.width             = 250
$User_name_val.height            = 20
$User_name_val.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,70)
#endregion

#region Account password
$Password_lbl                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Password_lbl.text               = "Password"
$Password_lbl.AutoSize           = $true
$Password_lbl.width              = 25
$Password_lbl.height             = 10
$Password_lbl.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,100)

$Password_ini_val                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
$Password_ini_val.multiline      = $false
$Password_ini_val.width          = 250
$Password_ini_val.height         = 20
$Password_ini_val.UseSystemPasswordChar = $true
$Password_ini_val.location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,100)

$Password_conf_val               = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
$Password_conf_val.multiline     = $false
$Password_conf_val.width         = 250
$Password_conf_val.height        = 20
$Password_conf_val.UseSystemPasswordChar = $true
$Password_conf_val.location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,130)
#endregion

#region Location of the user
$Location_lbl                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Location_lbl.text               = "Location"
$Location_lbl.AutoSize           = $true
$Location_lbl.width              = 25
$Location_lbl.height             = 10
$Location_lbl.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,160)

$Location_val                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Location_val.multiline          = $false
$Location_val.text               = "OU=Users,OU=ADM,DC=Mustangeng,DC=com"
$Location_val.width              = 250
$Location_val.height             = 20
$Location_val.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,160)
#endregion

#region Checkboxes
$Must_chg_pass                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Must_chg_pass.text              = "User must change password at next logon"
$Must_chg_pass.AutoSize          = $false
$Must_chg_pass.width             = 290
$Must_chg_pass.height            = 20
$Must_chg_pass.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,190)

$Cannot_chg_pass                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Cannot_chg_pass.text            = "User cannot change password"
$Cannot_chg_pass.AutoSize        = $false
$Cannot_chg_pass.width           = 250
$Cannot_chg_pass.height          = 20
$Cannot_chg_pass.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,220)
$Cannot_chg_pass.Checked         = $true

$Pass_not_expires                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Pass_not_expires.text           = "Password never expires"
$Pass_not_expires.AutoSize       = $false
$Pass_not_expires.width          = 250
$Pass_not_expires.height         = 20
$Pass_not_expires.location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,250)
$Pass_not_expires.Checked        = $true

$Account_disabled_val            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Account_disabled_val.text       = "Account is active"
$Account_disabled_val.AutoSize   = $false
$Account_disabled_val.width      = 250
$Account_disabled_val.height     = 20
$Account_disabled_val.location   = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,280)
$Account_disabled_val.Checked    = $false
#endregion

#region Description
$GECOS_lbl                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$GECOS_lbl.text                  = "Description"
$GECOS_lbl.AutoSize              = $true
$GECOS_lbl.width                 = 25
$GECOS_lbl.height                = 10
$GECOS_lbl.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,310)

$GECOS_val                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$GECOS_val.multiline             = $false
$GECOS_val.width                 = 250
$GECOS_val.height                = 20
$GECOS_val.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,310)
#endregion

#region Group membership
$ADGroups_lbl                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$ADGroups_lbl.text               = "AD Groups"
$ADGroups_lbl.AutoSize           = $true
$ADGroups_lbl.width              = 25
$ADGroups_lbl.height             = 10
$ADGroups_lbl.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,340)

$ADGroups_val                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$ADGroups_val.multiline          = $true
$ADGroups_val.width              = 250
$ADGroups_val.height             = 160
$ADGroups_val.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,340)
#endregion

#region Additional attributes
$Ext_Attribute5_lbl              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Ext_Attribute5_lbl.Text         = "Extension Attribute5"
$Ext_Attribute5_lbl.AutoSize     = $true
$Ext_Attribute5_lbl.Width        = 25
$Ext_Attribute5_lbl.Height       = 10
$Ext_Attribute5_lbl.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,510)

$Ext_Attribute5_val              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Ext_Attribute5_val.Text         = "Company name"
$Ext_Attribute5_val.Multiline    = $false
$Ext_Attribute5_val.Width        = 250
$Ext_Attribute5_val.Height       = 20
$Ext_Attribute5_val.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,510)

$Ext_Attribute10_lbl             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Ext_Attribute10_lbl.Text        = "Extension Attribute10"
$Ext_Attribute10_lbl.AutoSize    = $true
$Ext_Attribute10_lbl.Width       = 25
$Ext_Attribute10_lbl.Height      = 10
$Ext_Attribute10_lbl.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,540)

$Ext_Attribute10_val             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Ext_Attribute10_val.Text        = "Region"
$Ext_Attribute10_val.Multiline   = $false
$Ext_Attribute10_val.Width       = 250
$Ext_Attribute10_val.Height      = 20
$Ext_Attribute10_val.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,540)

$Ext_Attribute15_lbl             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Ext_Attribute15_lbl.Text        = "Extension Attribute15"
$Ext_Attribute15_lbl.AutoSize    = $true
$Ext_Attribute15_lbl.Width       = 25
$Ext_Attribute15_lbl.Height      = 10
$Ext_Attribute15_lbl.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,570)

$Ext_Attribute15_val             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Ext_Attribute15_val.Text        = "EH/WH"
$Ext_Attribute15_val.Multiline   = $false
$Ext_Attribute15_val.Width       = 250
$Ext_Attribute15_val.Height      = 20
$Ext_Attribute15_val.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,570)

$Job_Title_lbl                   = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Job_Title_lbl.Text              = "Job title"
$Job_Title_lbl.AutoSize          = $true
$Job_Title_lbl.Width             = 25
$Job_Title_lbl.Height            = 10
$Job_Title_lbl.Location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,600)

$Job_Title_val                   = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Job_Title_val.Text              = "NA"
$Job_Title_val.Multiline         = $false
$Job_Title_val.Width             = 250
$Job_Title_val.Height            = 20
$Job_Title_val.Location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,600)

$Department_lbl                  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Department_lbl.Text             = "Department"
$Department_lbl.AutoSize         = $true
$Department_lbl.Width            = 25
$Department_lbl.Height           = 10
$Department_lbl.Location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,630)

$Department_val                  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Department_val.Text             = "NA"
$Department_val.Multiline        = $false
$Department_val.Width            = 250
$Department_val.Height           = 20
$Department_val.Location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,630)

$Company_lbl                     = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Company_lbl.Text                = "Company"
$Company_lbl.AutoSize            = $true
$Company_lbl.Width               = 25
$Company_lbl.Height              = 10
$Company_lbl.Location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,660)

$Company_val                     = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Company_val.Text                = "IBM"
$Company_val.Multiline           = $false
$Company_val.Width               = 250
$Company_val.Height              = 20
$Company_val.Location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,660)
#endregion

#region Buttons
$Confirm_Button                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Confirm_Button.BackColor        = "#00ff00"
$Confirm_Button.text             = "OK"
$Confirm_Button.width            = 100
$Confirm_Button.height           = 30
$Confirm_Button.location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,690)
$Confirm_Button.Font             = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10,style=Bold'
$Create_ADuser = {
  if ($Password_ini_val.Text -cne $Password_conf_val.Text)
  {
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Passwords don't match")
  } elseif ($Password_ini_val.Text.Length -lt 8)
  {
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Password is too short")
  } else {
    $password = $Password_ini_val.Text | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $Display_name = $Display_name_val.Text + " [ADM]"
    New-ADUser -GivenName $First_name_val.Text -Surname $Second_name_val.Text -DisplayName $Display_name -AccountPassword $password -Path $Location_val.Text -Name $User_name_val.Text`
     -CannotChangePassword $Cannot_chg_pass.Checked -PasswordNeverExpires $Pass_not_expires.Checked -ChangePasswordAtLogon $Must_chg_pass.Checked -Enabled $Account_disabled_val.Checked`
     -Description $GECOS_val.Text -OtherAttributes @{'ExtensionAttribute5' = $Ext_Attribute5_val.Text;'ExtensionAttribute9' = "People";'ExtensionAttribute10' = $Ext_Attribute10_val.Text;`
     'ExtensionAttribute11' = "Other";'ExtensionAttribute12' = "No";'ExtensionAttribute14' = "NA";'ExtensionAttribute15' = $Ext_Attribute15_val.Text;'Division' = "WG Mustang"}`
     -Office "NA" -OfficePhone "NA" -Title $Job_Title_val.Text -Department $Department_val.Text -Company $Company_val.Text -SamAccountName $User_name_val.Text -PassThru | `
     Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf $ADGroups_val.Text
    $AD_user_creation.Close()
  }
}
$Confirm_Button.add_Click($Create_ADuser)


$Cancel_button                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Cancel_button.BackColor         = "#ff0000"
$Cancel_button.text              = "Cancel"
$Cancel_button.width             = 100
$Cancel_button.height            = 30
$Cancel_button.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(350,690)
$Cancel_button.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10,style=Bold'
<#$Cancel = {
    $AD_user_creation.Close()
    exit
}#>
$Cancel_button.add_Click({
    $AD_user_creation.Close()
    exit
})

$AD_user_creation.AcceptButton   = $Confirm_Button
$AD_user_creation.CancelButton   = $Cancel_button
#endregion

$AD_user_creation.controls.AddRange(@($Display_name_lbl,$First_name_val,$Second_name_val,$User_name_lbl,$Display_name_val,$User_name_val,$Password_lbl,$Password_ini_val,$Password_conf_val,$Location_lbl,`
$Location_val,$Must_chg_pass,$Cannot_chg_pass,$Pass_not_expires,$Account_disabled_val,$GECOS_lbl,$GECOS_val,$ADGroups_lbl,$ADGroups_val,$Ext_Attribute5_lbl,$Ext_Attribute5_val,$Ext_Attribute10_lbl,`
$Ext_Attribute10_val,$Ext_Attribute15_lbl,$Ext_Attribute15_val,$Job_Title_lbl,$Job_Title_val,$Department_lbl,$Department_val,$Company_lbl,$Company_val,$Confirm_Button,$Cancel_button))

$showFullName = { $Display_name_val.Text = ($First_name_val.Text + " " + $Second_name_val.Text) }

[void]$Second_name_val.Add_Leave( { & $showFullName } )
[void]$First_name_val.Add_Leave(  { & $showFullName } )

[void]$AD_user_creation.ResumeLayout()

$result = $AD_user_creation.ShowDialog()
[void]$AD_user_creation.Dispose()

Set-ExecutionPolicy $Orig_exec_policy -Force
```

Definitions of checkboxes start at the row 101 and user gets created at the rows 268-272.
The user sometimes gets created as active, sometimes as disabled. And once I notice that even the "user cannot change password" doesn't get checked in the account, even though the value in the form is set to True. I didn't notice any problems with the other checkboxes. Any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error stems from the way you use the `New-User` cmdlet. That piece of code looks complicated enough to not see that there is at least one backtick in the wrong place.

Better use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7) for this:

```
$params = @{
    'GivenName'             = $First_name_val.Text
    'Surname'               = $Second_name_val.Text
    'DisplayName'           = $Display_name
    'AccountPassword'       = $password
    'Path'                  = $Location_val.Text
    'Name'                  = $User_name_val.Text
    'CannotChangePassword'  = $Cannot_chg_pass.Checked
    'PasswordNeverExpires'  = $Pass_not_expires.Checked
    'ChangePasswordAtLogon' = $Must_chg_pass.Checked
    'Enabled'               = $Account_disabled_val.Checked
    'Description'           = $GECOS_val.Text
    'Office'                = "NA"
    'OfficePhone'           = "NA"
    'Title'                 = $Job_Title_val.Text
    'Department'            = $Department_val.Text
    'Company'               = $Company_val.Text
    'SamAccountName'        = $User_name_val.Text
    'OtherAttributes'       = @{'ExtensionAttribute5'  = $Ext_Attribute5_val.Text
                                'ExtensionAttribute9'  = "People"
                                'ExtensionAttribute10' = $Ext_Attribute10_val.Text
                                'ExtensionAttribute11' = "Other"
                                'ExtensionAttribute12' = "No"
                                'ExtensionAttribute14' = "NA"
                                'ExtensionAttribute15' = $Ext_Attribute15_val.Text
                                'Division'             = "WG Mustang"}
    'PassThru'              = $true
}
$newUser = New-ADUser @params
if ($newUser) {
    $newUser | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf $ADGroups_val.Text
}
else {
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Error creating new user")
}
```

Comment: It worked for a while but now it started to work incorrectly again. The `-Enabled` value of the account is sometimes set as true, sometimes as false, even though the relevant checkbox is always set to `$true`. I set the default value of the checkbox to `$true`, account was created as active several times, then suddenly as disabled. I set the default to `$false` and checked it in the form manually, account was created as active several times, then disabled again...

Comment: @PetrSynek To me it looks like you are negating the Enabled checkbox. The code uses `$Account_disabled_val` while the whole meaning is to **Enable**, not **disable** when checked.. If you follow that reversed logic, the code should read `'Enabled' = !($Account_disabled_val.Checked)`. (i.e. if NOT checked then the user is Enabled)

Comment: The checkbox name is historical, basically. Originally the text next to it was "Account is disabled" and I put negation to the `-Enabled` parameter's value, but it caused problems (don't remember any specifics anymore), so I just changed the text at the checkbox and removed the negation. But I kept the value's name, since that shouldn't affect anything. It's just a name.

Comment: @PetrSynek It should have been no problem repacing the checkbox name into what it actually stand for and not the reverse.. Question is of course.. Are you now using the splatting I proposed or are you still using the bad `New-ADUser` coding?? (looks like it seeing your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60223196/9898643) about the same thing. Also, have you fixed the multiline issue for the `$ADGroups_val` textbox?

Comment: I'm using the splatting now. I now tried to revert it back to the "disabled" text and negate it, since I formerly had the syntax of the negation incorrect (didn't use the brackets). Now I'm waiting for a tester to try it out. Unfortunately I don't have user permissions to create users myself.

Comment: Looks like some weird AD glitch. We created a user, it was disabled, but after some time became active. I never encountered this behaviour before...

Comment: @PetrSynek It takes time for domain controllers to synchronize. Perhaps that is what you saw. Meantime, you have un-accepted the answer, but really, there is nothing wrong with it and did address your problem..

Comment: Yes, I reaccepted. At first, when I again saw the account as disabled, I thought the solution did not work after all and therefore I unaccepted. As it obviously is the matter of DC synchronisation, I checked the tick again. Thanks for help.